# Best way to manage image orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I am trying to set different images on a UIImageView but I don´t know how to handle the image orientation because always that I call `image.imageOrientation` the result is `UIImageOrientationUp` and it isn´t. 
Here some examples:

[Image with wrong orientation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpv3Q.jpg)

[Image with wrong orientation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYHCO.jpg)

I want that all images look correctly but I don´t know how to do it if the `image.imageOrientation` don´t give me the correct value.

Here my code:

```
NSArray *paths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"porfileImage.png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
if (img == nil) {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user"];
}
NSLog(@"Orien: %ld",(long)img.imageOrientation);
self.porfileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img CGImage] scale:[img scale] orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error!!

I was saving the image using `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);` so the image lose the orientation and when I wanted to use it, the image already was a default orientation that isn´t the correct one.

The solution is to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);` instead of `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);` and for automatically the image save with the correct orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all the images clicked by a camera have `metadata`/ `EXIF data` which has the image orientation value. As the image is transmitted or passed along various channels like email, messaging etc. some of this data might be stripped off. So every time you load the image using CGImage, it takes the default orientation of `UIImageOrientationUp`.

One solution might be to create two versions of your image,  `UIImage` and `CGImage`, and compare their height. If they are equal, then the `CGImage` version is not be rotated and you are good. Else, the `CGImage` conversion has messed up the orientation. In that case, swap the x/y coordinate of origin and try to rotate it.

Comment: How can I create a CGImage from a path?

Comment: You are doing it already here [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img CGImage] scale:[img scale] orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];

Comment: Is not working, the UIImage height and CGImage height is always the same.

Comment: Glad you caught the issue.